# Angular and play framework Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: java, angular, playframework, cors

In my sample application, I have a get request performed via frontend(angular js),  to retrieve informations from my java backend(play framework).

My angular request is:

```
 function getGeneralInfo() {
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'sample' + 'generalInfo'}).
            success(function(response) {
                loadInfo(response);
            }).then(function(response){
                check();
            }).catch(function(e){
                console.log("failure getting info");
            });
    }
```

In my backend config file I add this options:

```
application.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN="*"
```

So when I execute the GET request from postman I get the results as expected, and all works fine.
But If I performe the request by Chrome browser I can see in the console this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.10.45:9000/sample/generalInfo' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And in my backend log I can see this stacktrace:

```
 - Internal server error, for (OPTIONS) [/sample/generalInfo
```

Why I see in the backend an options request while in frontend I send a get request?
How can I solve this mistake? thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's not a mistake, it is called `preflight request` browser makes it to get CORS headers and if there is no ones then GET request will not be done at all.
So you need to handle all options requests as well and put correct CORS headers there

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not explain  why even if I set the cors in this way: application.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = "*" the error persists